# Multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a program that takes an input number T(number of test cases), and then asks for the numbers N.

This is my code:

```
T = int(raw_input())
L = [int(raw_input()) for i in range(T)]
L1 = []
for i in range(0,L[i]):
    if (i%3 == 0 or i%5 ==0):
        L1.append(i)
print L1
```

> Input: `2 10 20`
>
> Output: `[0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18]`

I would like the output to be of the following format:

> `[[0, 3, 5, 6, 9], [0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18]]`

Here [0, 3, 5, 6, 9] is the list that has elements with both multiples of 3 and 5 for number 10

`[0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18]` is the list that has elements with both multiples of 3 and 5 for number 20

I am new to python. kindly let me know how I should proceed on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert it's not a duplicate since the optimal solution does not require splitting. It's better to create chunks upfront.

Comment: you are right indeed, sorry about that

Comment: Your (ab)use of the `i` variable from the first list comprehension is not going to continue to work when you move to Python 3. Just sayin'.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are even asking for `T` inputs if you are going to ignore them all but the last one.

Comment: Apparently, the outer loop is missing.

Comment: I can't even tell what's supposed to determine whether a number goes into the first sublist or the second.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question now

Comment: Now it matches what I initially expected. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will produce a `list` of `list`s containing all the multiples of 3 and 5 that are less than the given number.

```
L = [10,20]
L1 = []
for i in L:
    L2 = [] # initialize a new list
    for j in range(i):
        if not (j%3 and j%5): # use falsy values and DeMorgan's Law
            L2.append(j) # append to this list
    if L2: # use this if you don't want to keep empty lists
        L1.append(L2)
```

---

```
>>> L1
[[0, 3, 5, 6, 9], [0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is splitting a list by input values. Hope it helps

```
num = int(raw_input())
upperBounds= [int(raw_input()) for i in range(num)]
res= []
for upperBound in upperBounds:
    res.append([i for i in range(0,upperBound) if not (i % 3 and i % 5)])

output:

2
10
20
[[0, 3, 5, 6, 9], [0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by applying appropriate logic:

> if the element at index `0` we have to iterate from 0 to that element
>
> else we have to iterate form L[index-1] to L[index]

```
T = int(raw_input())
L = [int(raw_input()) for i in range(T)]
L1 = []
for j in xrange(len(L)):
   temp = []
   get = 0 if not j else L[j-1]
   # if j==0:
   #    get = 0
   # else:
   #    get = L[j-1]
   for i in range(get, L[j]):
      if (i%3 == 0 or i%5 ==0):
         temp.append(i)
   L1.append(temp)
print L1

>>> [[0, 3, 5, 6, 9], [10, 12, 15, 18]]
```

Or a more `Pythonic` and compacted version may look like:

```
T = int(raw_input())
L = [int(raw_input()) for i in range(T)]
L1 = []
for j in xrange(len(L)):
   get = 0 if not j else L[j-1]
   L1.append([i for i in range(get, L[j]) if (i%3 == 0 or i%5 ==0)])
print L1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generate a list of multiples with `range(l,u,s)` with `l` the lower bounds, `u` the upper bound and `d` the step.

Now if we want to generate multiples of `i` for a given range, we can use the following function:

```
def multiples(factor, lower, upper) :
    return set(range(lower+(factor-lower)%factor,upper,factor))
```

We thus manipulate the lower bound as `lower+(factor-lower)%factor` in order to search - in constant time - the first multiple that is greater than or equal to `lower`.

Next we need to multiples of `3` and `5`:

```
def multiples35(lower, upper):
    return sorted(list(multiples(3,lower,upper)|multiples(5,lower,upper)))
```

Now we only need to iterate over the list of values and generate the list of multiples for each two numbers:

```
def func(B):
    return [multiples35(0,upper) for upper in B]
```

Or as full code:

```
import sets

def multiples(factor, lower, upper) :
    return set(range(lower+(factor-lower)%factor,upper,factor))

def multiples35(lower, upper):
    return sorted(list(multiples(3,lower,upper)|multiples(5,lower,upper)))

def func(B):
    return [multiples35(0,upper) for upper in B]
```

The main function reads then:

```
T = int(raw_input())
B = [int(raw_input()) for i in range(T)]
print func(B)
```